# Posible to iterate list of CQ tags in jquery?

Tags: jquery, aem

I have a jsp variable "tagList" which contains a list of Tags (CQ5 Tags). This list needs to be displayed in a dropdown.

Since I have to use AJAX on change of the dropdown, I need to use jquery to iterate through "tagList" and display all tag titles in the dropdown.

Is it even possible ?

I tried a basic code but it alerts only "undefined".

```
$("#tagList").each(function(index) {
alert( index + ": " + $(this).title);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps try `$(this).title.text()` ?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do?? What happens when the onchange fires? You make a request to something and get new values or you want to capture the value to send the request? JSP is server side and Jquery is client side. It is not possible to access a server side variable in JS. Kindly add more details to the question, as it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Please show us a complete code example (JSP file and the JS script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're building a select list with JSP  Is this true? If so, then to iterate thru the list is fairly easy:

```
$("#taglist option").each(function(idx, val){
    alert(idx + " : " + $(this).val());
});
```

Find a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/richbuff/7tBAd/

Keep in mind that jQuery doesn't know about JSP tags. JavaScript (and thus jQuery) only knows about HTML and the DOM.

Hope this helps!